# Is there a standard pattern for creating worker classes with access to protected members?

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns

I just did something kind of wacky using a partial class and I'm wondering if there's an already established pattern that might have accomplished the same thing using a less confusing approach.

**The problem:**

- I had a base class with protected members and virtual methods designed for the derived class to do work when they are called.
- I wanted to delegate this work out to a list of workers.
- However I needed the workers to have access to the protected members.

**My probably overly complicated solution:**

Note: I realize this depends on the class being partial - I'm OK with that but it would be cool if there was a solution that didn't need it...

```
void Main()
{
    ABase aBase = new ADerived();
    aBase.DoWork();
}

public partial class ABase
{
    protected int state1 = 1;
    protected int state2 = 2;
    List<ABase> workers;

    public ABase()
    {
        workers = new List<ABase>();
        CreateWorkers(workers);
    }

    protected virtual void CreateWorkers(List<ABase> workers)
    {
    }

    public ABase(ABase aBase)
    {
        this.Target = aBase;
    }

    public virtual void DoWork()
    {
        foreach (var worker in this.workers)
        {
            worker.DoWork();
        }
    }

    protected ABase Target { get; private set; }
}

public partial class ABase
{
    public class Worker1 : ABase
    {
        public Worker1(ABase aBase) : base(aBase) { }

        public override void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine (Target.state1);
        }
    }

    public class Worker2 : ABase
    {
        public Worker2(ABase aBase) : base(aBase) { }

        public override void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine (Target.state2);
        }
    }
}

public class ADerived : ABase
{
    protected override void CreateWorkers(List<ABase> workers) 
    {
        workers.Add(new Worker1(this));
        workers.Add(new Worker2(this));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
```

Comment: Looks OK to me.  The workers are in the same base class as the protected members.

Comment: I don't think `ABase` needs to be partial, and `Worker1` does not need to be a nested class. Also, I would not have a Worker derive from a List of Workers (which is essentially what `ABase` is), but that becomes a matter of opinion.

Comment: if worker is not nested then access to protected members via reference to an instance of ABase is not possible (if I'm wrong about that I'll delete my question and reconsider it)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the design so that the workers weren't accessing instance fields at all.  I would have `DoWork` take a parameter with the information that they need and have the base class pass the state into the `DoWork` method.

```
public class MyState //TODO give better name
{
    public int State1 { get; set; }
    public int State2 { get; set; }
}

public class ABase
{
    public MyState state = new MyState()
    {
        State1 = 1,
        State2 = 2
    };

    List<Action<MyState>> workers = new List<Action<MyState>>();

    public ABase()
    {
        CreateWorkers();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        foreach (var action in workers)
        {
            action(state);
        }
    }

    private void CreateWorkers()
    {
        workers.Add(new Worker1().DoWork);
        workers.Add(Worker2.Process);
    }
}

public class Worker1
{
    public void DoWork(MyState state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(state.State1);
    }
}

public class Worker2
{
    public static void Process(MyState state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(state.State2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's cleaner... this is a demonstration of inheritance vs. composition, right?

Comment: @AaronAnodide Basically, yes.